# How to handle this model association based on a enumeration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model, User.rb.

Now I have a table that looks like:

```
user_something

user_id
something_id
something_type
```

The value of something_type comes from a enumeration I have in my rails code.
The something_id can be an id from many other tables, meaning it represenets the id of lots of db tables, and the something_type will tell me if it is an article, or whatever.

So now say on my Article.rb model, **I want to create an association to the user_something table, which will list all rows where the something_type = 3, and the something_id = article_id.**

```
select * from user_something where something_type = 3 and something_id = xxx
```

*The query would have to inner join with the users table to get me a collection of Users.*

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Something like:

```
class User
  belongs_to :somethingable, :polymorphic=>true
end

class OtherClass
  has_many :users, :as => :somethingable
end

class YetAnotherClass
  has_many :users, :as => :somethingable
end
```

Comment: but where does my ruby enumeration fit in?

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you're using the enumeration?  I can't tell from the question exactly what you're looking for.